# String with HEX to array[] of int8?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

How to convert string hex, into array of int 8?

```
var hash : string;
    x: array[0..19] of int8;

begin
   hash := '713BD6D36D4964F4E4F843CB03D118EA5C372FF6';
   put_hash_into_x(hash);
end;
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you need to have the hash in a hex string in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [HexToBin](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.HexToBin):

```
HexToBin(PChar(hash), x, SizeOf(x));
```

Now, the docs say:

> The hexadecimal number must use lower-case characters; **HexToBin** does not recognize upper-case characters.

But it turns out that this statement is incorrect and `HexToBin` works no matter what case text you give it.

Comment: The documentation is wrong. `HexToBin()` does support uppercase letters, and has for a long long time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. That will teach me to read the documentation rather than the source!!